# How can I call a method if my Ionic 2 range slider changes value

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm working on an Ionic 2 app and playing around with the range, as described here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/range/Range/

Call me crazy, but I can't find anywhere on google how the range component can call a method in my .ts class once the value has changed.

Something like a button, which goes like this:

```
<button ion-button (click)="myMethod($event)">
```

Of course, I need the value of the slider. In my case I defined it as follows:

```
  <ion-range min="0" max="10" color="danger">
    <ion-label range-left>0</ion-label>
    <ion-label range-right>10</ion-label>
  </ion-range>
```

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is right in the docs in the section [output-events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/range/Range/#output-events):

> `ionChange` Expression to evaluate when the range value changes.

Use it as follows:

```
<ion-range min="0" max="10" color="danger" (ionChange)="myMethod($event)">
  <ion-label range-left>0</ion-label>
  <ion-label range-right>10</ion-label>
</ion-range>
```

Comment: I feel silly.. Must have had my eyes closes while I browsed through the docs. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way.

```js
public myMethod(newRangeValue){
 console.log("Range :"+newRangeValue); 
}
```

```html
<ion-range min="0" max="10" color="danger" [(ngModel)]="modelRange" (ionChange)="myMethod($event)">
  <ion-label range-left>0</ion-label>
  <ion-label range-right>10</ion-label>
</ion-range>
New value : {{modelRange}}
```